# How to use spread syntax or destructuring into `this` value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, code-structure

I know we can do something like:

```
const a = { b: 1, c: 2 }

const A = { ...a };
// A { b: 1, c: 2 }
```

But how do we use this approach to pass data into `this` value?

For example we have a `class A {}` and want to dynamically set object property into `this`. The usual way would be using `Object.defineProperties` with maybe `for...in` loop:

```
const a = { b: 1, c: 2 }

class A {
  constructor(obj){
    for (const k in obj)
      Object.defineProperty(this, k, { value: obj[k] });
  }
}

new A(a);
// A { b: 1, c: 2 }
```

So I'm thinking, since we have the syntactic sugar now, how can we utilise it to the example above?

**EDIT**

I am talking about spread <s>operator</s> syntax `...` here.

Comment: you can't use `...` to put values in `this` because `this` is a reserved keyword, and you can't use reserved keywords as variable names

Comment: ...and you shouldn't really want to. `this` is an `A` instance. If you replace it, it won't be an instance of your class anymore, which defeats the purpose of making a class.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: "*The usual way would be using Object.defineProperties*" - no, it would be a simple assignment, like `this[k] = obj[k];`. Why did you use `Object.defineProperty`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't update `this` by spreading and then assigning the result.

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy properties from the `obj` to `this`:

```js
class A {
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
}

const a = { b: 1, c: 2 }

console.log(new A(a));
```

You can use destructuring to assign known properties to `this`:

```js
class A {
  constructor(obj) {
    ({ b: this.b, c: this.c } = obj);
  }
}

const a = { b: 1, c: 2 }

console.log(new A(a));
```

Comment: upvoted =) but sir it seems there's a typo in the last snippet which brings the wrong result.

Comment: `({ b: this.b, b: this.c } = obj)` should be `({ b: this.b, c: this.c } = obj)`. No?

Comment: @YongQuan - indeed. Fixed.